# Returning NULL if cannot join

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables:

`Providers`

```
----------------------------
| ID | NAME                |
----------------------------
| 1  | Dr. Brown           |
----------------------------
| 2  | Dr. Smith           |
----------------------------
| 3  | Nurse Jones         |
----------------------------
| 4  | Stan Lee, NP        |
----------------------------

Provider_Tax_ID
----------------------------
| ID | TAX_ID              |
----------------------------
| 2  | 79465654            |
----------------------------
| 3  | 32613322            |
----------------------------
```

When trying to match `Providers` with their tax IDs, I'd like to pull all providers, including ones that cannot be joined to `Provider_Tax_ID`.

So my result would look like:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID | NAME                | TAX_ID              |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Dr. Brown           | NULL                |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2  | Dr. Smith           | 79465654            |
--------------------------------------------------
| 3  | Nurse Jones         | 32613322            |
--------------------------------------------------
| 4  | Stan Lee, NP        | NULL                |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried something like this, but I'm not getting any results:

```
SELECT 
    p.ID,
    p.NAME,
    t.TAX_ID
FROM
    providers p
        FULL OUTER JOIN provider_tax_id t on p.ID = t.ID
```

Comment: Although a `left outer join` makes more sense in your case, the `full outer join` should return what you are looking for.  What is it returning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a left (outer) join:

```
SELECT 
    p.ID,
    p.NAME,
    t.TAX_ID
FROM
    providers p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN provider_tax_id t on p.ID = t.ID
```